# Error Code: 1066. Not unique table/alias: 'circle_call_prefixes'

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to update my tables using `INNER JOIN`

but i keep getting this error

> Error Code: 1066. Not unique table/alias: 'circle_call_prefixes'

this is my code:

```
UPDATE circle_call_destinations , circle_call_prefixes
INNER JOIN circle_call_prefixes ON circle_call_prefixes.circle = circle_call_destinations.destination
SET circle_call_prefixes.prefix = '1' ,
      circle_call_destinations.circle = '2'
WHERE circle_call_destinations.autoNo = '20'
```

thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question, but I had exactly the same error...

You should remove the extra ", circle_call_prefixes" in the first line.

The right syntax is

```
UPDATE T1
INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.a = T2.a
SET .....
```

There is no T2 between UPDATE and INNER.